# Redirect with incoming parameters - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am using url based languages and i have a page with incoming parameters in URL.

I do not like query strings ('?x=y') or named params ('x:y') in URL so i use **http://localhost/cakeapp/us/controller/action/param1/param2/param3**

In my *AppController* i am checking if the URL has language defined, if no language is defined (for example the user requests *http://localhost/cakeapp/controller/action/param1/param2/param3*) then i want to simply redirect the user to the language defined URL with the same parameters.

In Short:
I want to redirect:

*http://localhost/cakeapp/controller/action/param1/param2/param3*

to

*http://localhost/cakeapp/us/controller/action/param1/param2/param3*

I use;

> $this->redirect(
>
> > Router::url(array('language' => $this->Session->read('Config.language'), 'base' => false))
>
> );

But it redirects user to *http://localhost/cakeapp/us/controller/action* without parameters.

Is there a way to build url using Router::url with incoming *$this->passedArgs* variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ensure you pass the parameters to the redirect method:

```
function controllerAction($param1, $param2, $param3) {

    $this->redirect(

        Router::url(array('language' => $this->Session->read('Config.language'), 'base' => false)),
        $param1,
        $param2,
        $param3
    );

}
```

Or at least in some way pass your parameters into the redirect method, whichever way is most appropriate for you.  I think you could do this too, if you are not passing the parameters directly as arguments into your controller action method:

```
$this->redirect(

    Router::url(array('language' => $this->Session->read('Config.language'), 'base' => false)),
    $this->request->params['named'][0],
    $this->request->params['named'][1],
    $this->request->params['named'][2]
);
```

Comment: Seems OK, but i wonder why does it redirect to the correct controller and action even though i did not pass them to the redirect method? But i have to pass the parameters?

Comment: I do not know how many params income. So how can i pass params to redirect method? They are in $this->passedArgs. I can't pass array to redirect method (it expects params as strings) and if i use _implode("/", $this->passedArgs)_, it converts /'s to %2F's in URL (encodes).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Router::connect(
    '/cakeapp/:language/:controller/:action/*',
    array(), 
    array('language'=>'[a-z]{2}')
);
Router::redirect(
    '/*', 
    '/cakeapp/us/'.substr(Router::url(null, false), 
    strpos(Router::url(null, false), '/', 1))
);
```

You can leave out the string manipulation in the second row if you don't have an app prefix; like so:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:language/:controller/:action/*', 
    array(), 
    array('language'=>'[a-z]{2}')
);
Router::redirect('/*', '/us/'.Router::url(null, false));
```

Comment: Thanks, now the tricky part: my site can use multiple languages in the url, so it is not only "_us_". How to make it dynamic too? It can be "_en_, _de_, _it_, etc"

Comment: The routing is a PHP file, so you can for example determine the language code you want to redirect to before the above `Router::` commands, put it into a variable, say $languageCode, and modify the `redirect` lines above to `Router::redirect('/*', '/cakeapp/'.$languageCode.'/'.substr...`